# Fade in/Fade out of Words in Array List using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like for the fade in/fade out to work for each word, one after the other. However, it either displays the last word in the array or everything together. I'm using animate.css and I'm trying to use JQuery to effect this transition of words. Please advise. thanks

```
   <script>
    var classes = [ '<h1 class="animated infinite rotateOutUpLeft">Software        </h1>',
            '<h1 class="animated infinite rotateOutUpLeft">project </h1>',
            '<h1 class="animated infinite rotateOutUpLeft">Engineering</h1>',  
            '<h1 class="animated infinite rotateOutUpLeft">Science</h1>'
        ];

         var display;
            // var i = 10000000;
           for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
                document.write(i);
                $("#tst").empty();
                 $("#tst").append(classes[i]);
                // setTimeout(function(){alert('join');}, 10000);
                // $("#tst").append(classes[i]);
                // setTimeout(function(){$("#tst").append(classes[i]);}, 6000);
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow. Please take a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help section. If you supply a code example illustrating what you've tried you are more likely to receive good answers

Comment: reminds me of southpark episode apple terms and condition

Comment: Greensock does a great job animating text: https://greensock.com/SplitText

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the code to just change the word every six seconds while CSS takes are of the fading? If so, this might work:

```
var i = 0;
$("#tst").html(classes[i]);
setInterval(function() {
    i = (i + 1) % classes.length;
    $("#tst").html(classes[i]);
}, 6000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opa5tbru/)

Or:

```
(function displayClass(i) {
    $("#tst").html(classes[i]);
    setTimeout(function() {
        displayClass((i + 1) % classes.length);
    }, 6000);
})(0);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca9cq19s/)

If you want the code to do the fading:

```
var classes = ['Software', 'project', 'Engineering', 'Science'];
(function displayClass(i) {
    $('#tst h1').text(classes[i]).fadeIn(1000).delay(600).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        displayClass((i + 1) % classes.length);
    });
})(0);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmLepb0p/2/)

Comment: Thanks John S. The two first set of codes you wrote worked the way I wanted it to except that it doesn't have the fading. The third, I tried running but it didn't work. I am not sure why but I think it may have to do with the version of jquery I'm using("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js") as the fadeIn function does nothing. I am very grateful for your input. Can you also explain why my code didn't work? I noticed javascript seems to not execute in a sequential manner as other languages.

Comment: @wmorris - I have updated the jsfiddle so the `<h1>` element is initially hidden. Now the element fades in the first time too. I also shortened the code. The animation functions queue up, so I didn't need to use the one callback function.

Comment: @wmorris - Are you saying it never fades in, but it does fade out? There should be no difference with this code for the version of jQuery you are using. As for JavaScript not executing sequentially, when callback functions are passed to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` they are not executed until later. Also, jQuery functions that animate an element use `setInterval` internally.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. It worked perfectly. Thanks a million,